# Get response from PayPal buttton in django

Tags: javascript, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated PayPal buttons into my project. I am sharing my code here for PayPal Buttons.

```js
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MyClientID&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>

<script>
function initPayPalButton() {
    paypal
      .Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: "rect",
          color: "blue",
          layout: "horizontal",
          label: "buynow",
        },

        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{amount: {currency_code: "USD", value: totalAmount}}],
          });
        },

        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
            // Full available details
            console.log("Capture result", orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById("paypal-button-container");
            element.innerHTML = "";
            element.innerHTML = "<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>";

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
          });
        },

        onError: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        },
      })
      .render("#paypal-button-container");
  }
  initPayPalButton();
</script>
```

```html
<div class="paypalButton-mainDiv">
  <div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am not able to get the response back from this code after Payment. I need to get the response and want to store it in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no data persistence happens when you have a successful payment.

You can use `onApprove` to get the response after payment and then send it to your server using an AJAX call or a form submit. That would look something like this:

```
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
        // [anything before]

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/<your-server-endpoint>');
        // optional: set header
        // xhr.setRequestHeader(/*<headers you need>*/);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('Response received: ' + xhr.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(orderData));

        // [anything after, e.g. element.innerHTML = <html> OR go to another URL ]

      });
    },
```

Even more ideally, you can use a form, rather than AJAX; in that case, you need to create a hidden `<input>` element that stores the response and then submit the form using JavaScript.

The exact specifications of these are up to you, and are doable as per the standard JS documentation.

Comment: For this `<your-server-endpoint>` I need to set the Webhook URL in the PayPal SendBox account right? And sorry for the late response.

Comment: @HMS not sure, I',m not super familiar with PayPal; the matter is, with a POST request, you can submit `orderData` as an HTTP payload. That way, you have access to that data, and you can persist if, e.g. save to a database.

Comment: Thank you for your response I get my desired output after adding CSRF_Token in your code.